# Any idiomatic expression in American English for eating too much?

Tags: idioms

Is there any idiomatic expression in American English for eating too much? I would especially want to have an expression that could be applied in a situation when the action of excessive eating is taking place at the moment of speaking. For example, if the idiomatic expression is, say, "to expand one's belly" then it could be used this way in the following situation:

> Having spent the whole morning looking for Jack, Peter finally gave up
>   and decided to have a cup of coffee at the "Swagger's". As soon as he
>   entered it, he saw Jack sitting inside at one table and consuming
>   probably the third portion of his favorite smoked chicken. "Here you
>   are/he is!" cried Jack with anger. "I've been running everywhere
>   trying to find you/him, but you are/he is sitting here and **expanding
>   your/his belly**! Very nice!"

Answer (score 13, accepted):

*Pigging out* and *stuffing one's face* come to mind:

> …he is sitting here and *pigging out*!
>
> …he is sitting here and *stuffing his face*!

Comment: In the context of the asker's quote, "stuffing your face" is perfect.

Answer (score 3):

What about *gorging* oneself?

"He is sitting here gorging himself!"

Comment: That's the one I'd have gone for too

Answer (score 0):

Well as far as I know in English:

```
We eat as a horse. //too much
We eat like a bird. //too little
We are hungry like a bear. //very hungry
```

Comment: hmmm, I could be wrong, not being American, but these examples don't seem idiomatic to me.

Comment: and Duran Duran is hungry like the wolf.

Comment: Eating like a horse is not eating too much. It is eating a *lot*, yes. But it implies that you are eating to work -- like a horse. Likewise eating like a bird isn't eating *too* little. It says you're eating sparingly - pecking like a bird - but makes no judgement about whether that's too much. Perhaps you have already eaten. *Hungry like a bear* is not familiar to me. Maybe it's common in Canada/Alaska where they have bears?

Comment: he he +1 @slim . Great explanations. Well I am not quite sure that I am able to see the difference between expression and idiom. Actually if I were in his shoes I would say something like:"If you are stuffing yourself so much we wont need fat turkey next Christmas." :D Not sure that this will be expression either. :P